# Connecting MongoDB replica read only Secondary from Spring boot application

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, replicaset

We got a mongodb replica set with three node (Say A,B,C)
When A and B are down, mongo makes the node C as read only (which is great!)

Our requirement is, when, only read only stand by node is availale(no primary), application should be still continue to work in read only mode.

If I use java MongoClient library with mongo client connection opetion 
**?readPreference=secondaryPreferred**, client program able to connect to mongo and read data from read only secondary node (no write as expected).

But if I try the same from Spring boot application, while application boot up Mongo Client is not able to connect to the available read only secondary, tt throws below error. Is there any parameter I can pass extra in Spring boot application to let application know it need to connect to read only secondary?

-----application.properties----

spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://10.9.9.71:27017,10.9.9.71:27018,10.9.9.71:27019/?readPreference=secondaryPreferred

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=10.9.9.71:27018, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}, {address=10.9.9.71:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}, {address=10.9.9.71:27019, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, roundTripTime=1.8 ms, state=CONNECTED}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=10.9.9.71:27018, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}, {address=10.9.9.71:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}, {address=10.9.9.71:27019, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, roundTripTime=1.8 ms, state=CONNECTED}]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)

Comment: Multiple projects in my company having same issue.  Spring wants writable access to Mongodb and times out because Mongodb instance is readonly.  Mongodb instance is readonly because it is a Disaster Recovery instance somehow tied to Production.

Answer (score 7):

Oh boy, at last got to know why it was failing.

In my mongo entity pojo, there are annotations to generate indexes etc
So during Spring boot strap, those entities were getting initialised and was trying to write into database. And that was failing the Spring bootstrap..